# How to make installer for Mac that detects Java version and installs if necessary

Tags: java, ios, installation, bundler

I've searched for this answer and I find things that are similar for Windows, but not for Mac.  I have an old program that is used on Windows, but not Macs yet.  I did not write it, but I have decompiled it to get the code.  It looks like it shouldn't be that hard to make it work on Mac, but I want to make a nice installer so my users will want to try it.  I have only recently gotten back into the programming game, so I am learning.

I have been investigating how to make a Windows installer that detects the Java version and then installs the correct one if necessary.  Is there such a thing for a Mac installer?  I have never worked on a Mac so I do not know how its guts work.  I have a friend with a Mac who is willing to beta-test for me.  I have one lib file that the program needs, plus an icon file.  The lib file may need to be changed in the future.  It's just a text file.  So I would like the icon and the lib file to be part of the package.

I've seen that there is a Java app bundler for Mac, but it's not obvious that it a) checks the Java version and installs the right one or b) that I can include other files in the bundle.

I appreciate any guidance you can give me.

Comment: As near as I can tell, Apple doesn't want me to be able to make an installer from my PC and Apple seems to detect the need for Java for me.  I've purchased a used Mac and will try to put together an installer there.  Thanks, Apple.